# SFDX mdapi convert does not generate necessary object-meta.xml

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, scratch-org

I have a simple package that I pulled down from my production org that I am now looking to `push:source` to a scratch org. The issue is that when I run

`sfdx force:mdapi:convert -r test/unpackaged`

I get a converted source structure within my `force-app/main/default/objects/` but without the necessary object-meta.xml that source needs to perform the push, for example:

**Account.object-meta.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata"/>
```

Leaving me with the following error:

```
ERROR:  Expected metadata file at source path: ../force-app/main/default/objects/Account/Account.object-meta.xml.
```

I've run an update on my CLI as that was initially a concern but even after the update I still get the same results. I've deleted my source and tried multiple times to see if it was just a glitch, but this continues to happen without fail. Any suggestions or thoughts? Anyone else experiencing the same issue?

Comment: One thing I'm seeing now when I refresh the entire scratch org and attempt this it no longer expects the `Account.object-meta.xml` So it's possible this is just another case of lose artifacts being tracked in a scratch org's `sourcePathInfos.js`, hence a new org on first push wouldn't require that component.

Answer (score 0):

Please verify that you have Account.object xml file in your Source pulled from Production.

When you pull Standard object, you have to specify them explicitly:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m CustomObject:Account
```

or by Ant

```
<types>
    <members>Account</members>
    <name>CustomObject</name>
</types>
```

So if you use just

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>CustomObject</name>
</types>
```

your Account.object XML file won't be retrieved from your production org, thus, won't be converted into Account.object-meta.xml